# HTTPS SSL Self-Signed Certificate with CA Certificate issue

Tags: http, https, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have a website on our Internal network that is also accessible to the public. I have purchased and installed an SSL certificate for that public site. The site is available using both https://site.domain.com (Public) and https://site.domain.local (Internal).

The problem I am having is creating and installing a self-signed certificate for the internal "site.domain.local" so that people on our internal network do not get the security warning. I have a keystore in the root folder and also created a self-signed certificate in that keystore with no luck. The public key is working just fine. I am running Debian linux with Tomcat 7 installed and I am also using Active Directory on the network with Microsoft DNS. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more details, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your set-up, but you could front your Tomcat with Apache, install the cert on the Apache instance and then do a Reverse-Proxy (plain http) to your Tomcat instance. People would access the Apache instance which would handle the SSL connection.

Comment: I can do that, but the certificate problem would still exist. The server resides behind the Firewall on my network and is accessible using both a domain.local name and a domain.com (via NAT and assigned public IP) and only if someone is off network can they connect to the domain.com server name and the certificate validates that name. I need to find a way to have a self-signed certificate on the server for internal users and then have it verify the domain.local name as well. Need to have both self-signed and CA certs installed.

Comment: I guess I really do not get what you mean by 'the certificate validates that name'. You can configure VirtualHosts on Apache, that will present different server certificates depending on the domain name people are accessing it with (check the ServerName directive)

Comment: For example, when my users are on the Internet from home or a cafe, they can enter in the site.domain.com name and not have an issue connecting to our site which is a NAT through our firewall. When they are on the local network, we are using AD and it is setup with the default domain.local. (instead of .com) Since all my users are behind the firewall they cannot connect to the site.domain.com, but have to use site.domain.local and the certificate I have installed from the CA is specifically for site.domain.com. I got a good suggestion yesterday as to a fix and will let you know how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add the CA certificate in every client certificate trusted store (which is not convenient) : the client click on the *certificate warning* message and install/trust the self signed x509 CA certificate. If this doesn't work, there is a problem with the certificate (though most openssl generated stuff .CER/.CRT/.P12/.PFX will install with no problem under recent windows).

If one client accepts the self-signed certificate with manual setup, you can try to install these certificates with Active Directory ; basically you add trusted CA cert within your AD, and client automagically synchronize (nb: mostly on login) : See there for a hint about setting thing up with AD : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295663/en-us (You may try this or dig in that direction : with AD, you never know).

Another possibility would be to set up your internal DNS to point `site.domain.com` to the local web site address (the *easy way*). You can test this setup with you `/etc/hosts` file on linux/unix flavours (or `system32/drivers/etc/hosts` on windows flavours)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will be trying to do this tomorrow. I have added the entry in the host file on one of my Windows servers, and it worked beautifully. I however, can not find a way to add the DNS entry record on my Windows DNS server. I will try the link you provided to add the certificate via AD.

Answer (score 0):

If your certificate is for site.domain.com and users are going to site.domain.local and getting that cert, then clearly there is a name mismatch and the browser will always warn you.

You either need to :

- get the cert regenerated with BOTH names
- get a cert for just the internal site
- mangle DNS so that when your internal users go to site.domain.com
  they get the IP address of site.domain.local.